# Intranet Uptime Monitoring Component

Tags: iis, intranet, uptime

I have a MOSS 2007 test site, its not public facing, instead its on our intranet, I am looking for an uptime monitoring component thats free and easy to install, any suggestions?

Update: I don't need graphs or anything fancy, I just need to make sure that I get a notification via email if the site goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) might be overkill, but it is not too hard to put in place ...

Answer (score 0):

I also came across OpManager - http://manageengine.adventnet.com/products/opmanager/

There is a free version which allows monitoring of 10 services.

I tried to get it to install on my SQL 2008 Server, but ended up just using the product default mySQL installation.

I also decided to uninstall it after 10 minutes worth of use, it seems like a great tool for a fully qualified network administrator, but it adds too much bloat to have it installed on my development server.